# Pandas DataFrame eval with space in column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, eval

I was looking at pandas DataFrame eval method ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html#pandas.DataFrame.eval)) which I find a nice syntactic sugar and could also help [enhancing performances](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#enhancingperf-eval).

This is the example from the docs:

```
from numpy.random import randn
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(randn(10, 2), columns=list('ab'))
df.eval('a + b')
```

How can I use `eval` when there is a space in my column names?
Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(10, 2), columns=["Col 1", "Col 2"])
```

I tried this:

```
df.eval('"Col 1" + "Col 2"')
```

but this gives error:

```
TypeError: data type "Col 1" not understood
```

Comment: Since it is not a built-in method, *DataFrame* needs to be qualified per rules of Python. You might have meant `pd.DateFrame` or `from pandas import DataFrame`?

Comment: @cs95 how can this be a duplicated of a question asked one year after this one?

Comment: Duplicates don't have to be asked in chronological order. I closed this because there's an answer there explaining how you can use backticks to support spaces in 0.25.

Comment: thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 5):

```
pd.eval('df["Col 1"] + df["Col 2"]')
```

This keeps the argument to eval as a string but is less clean than the example without spaces in the column names

example:

```
print(df)

      Col 1     Col 2
0 -0.206838 -1.007173
1 -0.762453  1.178220
2 -0.431943 -0.804775
3  0.830659 -0.244472
4  0.111637  0.943254
5  0.206615  0.436250
6 -0.568307 -0.680140
7 -0.127645 -0.098351
8  0.185413 -1.224999
9  0.767931  1.512654

print(pd.eval('df["Col 1"] + df["Col 2"]'))

0   -1.214011
1    0.415768
2   -1.236718
3    0.586188
4    1.054891
5    0.642865
6   -1.248447
7   -0.225995
8   -1.039586
9    2.280585
dtype: float64
```

**EDIT**

After some investigation, it looks like the above method works in either python 2.7 or 3.6 if you are using the python engine:

```
pd.eval('df["Col 1"] + df["Col 2"]', engine='python')
```

However, this does not give you the performance advantage that the `numexpr` engine can provide. In python 2.7, this method works:

```
pd.eval('df["Col 1"] + df["Col 2"]', engine='numexpr')
```

but in python 3.6 you get the error `ValueError: unknown type str160`.

My guess is that this is because pandas is passing a unicode string to `numexpr` in 3.6 but a bytestring in 2.7 .  I'm guessing that this problem is related to [this issue](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/issues/142) and maybe [this one](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/issues/141) as well.

Comment: did you test it? It gives me `ValueError: unknown type str160` (Pandas 0.20.1). What is your Pandas version?

Comment: @MaxU, I believe so... (see the example).  Are there further tests you would recommend?

Comment: Could you specify your Pandas version? I'd like to test it myself...

Comment: @MaxU It works for me in two versions: 0.19.2 (on python 2.7) and 0.20.3 (on python 3.6). Also, I'm using numpy versions 1.11.1 and 1.12.0 respectively

Comment: @MaxU Use `engine='python'`.

Comment: @bunji, i got it! Most probably you don't have `numexpr` installed, so `pd.eval` falls back to `python` engine as Goyo just written

Comment: @Goyo, yeah, i think this is it. If `numexpr` is not installed, `pd.eval()` falls back to `engine='python'`

Comment: @MaxU yup. I just tried it on another machine with numexpr installed and got the same error. Good catch. This is really too bad since numexpr is what's giving the performance advantage in the first place.

Comment: @MaxU It looks like the error is caused because pandas passes a unicode string to numexpr.  So, interestingly, with python 2.7 this works using the numexpr engine since it is passing bytestrings which numexpr can handle.

Comment: @bunji, this is an interesting finding! Can you extend your answer? This might help people having similar problem...

Comment: @bunji, moreover - if we replace spaces with underscores in column names - `df.eval("Col_1 + Col_2")` works in Python 2.7 and it does NOT work in Python 3.6...

Comment: @MaxU Ok, that is weird. `df.eval('Col_1 + Col_2', engine='numexpr')` works for me in both 3.6 and 2.7

Comment: Might be too late to the party but according to Pandas doc : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html 
engine='python' seems to be bad choice. As per the doc : "level python. This engine is generally not that useful." 
I was looking it up for a different issue and came across this question.

Comment: For those that actually want to know the answer, look in the question that shows the "duplicate" question: use backticks. What should work is ``df.eval('`col 1` + `col 2`')``

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using:

```
df.eval(df["Col 1"] + df["Col 2"])
```

But that is kind of going against the purpose of the eval function.

Alternatively, you can rename your columns in order to make them compatible with the eval syntax:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_'))
```

Comment: Yes, agreed it is against the purpose of the eval function :)

Comment: ++ for renaming columns

Comment: I just tested it... `df.query("Col_1 + Col_2")` after renaming columns gives me `KeyError`. `pd.eval("df.Col_1 + df.Col_2")` works, but it's not that handy compared to `DataFrame.eval()` IMO...

Comment: @MaxU This actually works for me, as you can see in the screenshot :https://prnt.sc/g0zeh5

Comment: @Thundzz, yeah, please see my last comment to bunji's answer... ;-)

Comment: @MaxU Actually, you were right. I am also getting a `KeyError` when I call `query` instead of `eval`

Comment: A conclusion for myself - better don't use spaces or underscores in column  names ;-)

Comment: underscore no longer works either

Answer (score 0):

thank you @Thundzz

```
    df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_'))
```

this snippet works well!

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question; instead, it ignores the question and resolves it by interspacing underscores.